# ReportViewer control bug in IE9 regarding multiple value paramater

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

This is what the microsoft sample *Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2* looks like in IE9 using WebForms ReportViewer 2010:

[image]

If I change IE9 to emulate IE7 or IE8, it looks like:

[image]

This particular parameter is a multiple value parameter with no available values set.

The first image should have commas between the values and results in the following error message:

> The value provided for the report parameter 'CategoryQuota' is not
>   valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)

Is there a way to fix this?